# Use of "Mounted /system" with secret key combinations in recovery;

Tags: recovery-mode, 5.1-lollipop, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I just discovered that after pressing a secret key combination in recovery mode, the log below shows a message "Mounted /system". What's this used for? Thank you!

Comment: Which log? I can't find it

Comment: In my device, running 5.1.1, it has a log in 'the recovery start menu' under the options (reboot system now, wipe data, etc.) which shows text in yellow font. For example, when I select "reboot system now" it shows "Rebooting..." for a couple of seconds before rebooting. And when the battery level is low it shows " E:battery level is too low to perform factory reset". And after pressing the secret key combination it just shows "Mounted /system"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` option im recovery mode allows you to mount a partition , like `SYSTEM` or `DATA` etc. Like you would do with a computer drive.  This  allows you to modify anything in that partition. Because when you boot in recovery mode, the other partitions are not mounted, you cannot see data or edit them.

The `mount /system` in the stock recovery [allows to mount the system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/ec28340) for some reason. I'm sure it has to do something with debugging.